# Sobolev space dense

Tags: functional-analysis

Consider the Hilbert space $L^2([-L,L])$.

Is the Sobolev space $H^2([-L,L])\subset L^2([-L,L])$ dense?

(Maybe this can be seen from the reason why $L^2([-L,L])$ is a Hilbert space?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, for any bounded domain $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$, the space $H^2(\Omega) \subset L^2(\Omega)$ is dense. See Theorem 2 in Sec. 5.3.2 in Evans' "Partial Differential Equations", where it is shown that all elements in the Sobolev space $W^{k,p}(\Omega)$ (the space of $k$ times weakly differentiable functions in $L^p$, with derivatives in $L^p$) can be approximated by functions in $C^\infty(\Omega)$.

Comment: I do not see why this implies that $H^2(\Omega)$ is dense in $L^2(\Omega)$. What you wrote means that $C^{\infty}(\Omega)$ is dense in $W^{k,p}(\Omega)$. Do we also have that $C^{\infty}(\Omega)$ is dense in $L^p(\Omega)$?

Comment: Absolutely! $L^p = W^{0,p}$. The point is that the smooth functions are dense in all of these spaces, so since $C^\infty \subset H^2 \subset L^2$, $H^2$ must be dense in $L^2$.